# Is this HTML structure valid? UL > DIV > { LI, LI } , DIV > { LI, LI } , DIV > { LI, LI }

Tags: html

Is this HTML structure valid?

```
<ul class="blog-category">
  <div class="three column">
    <li>Item 1</li> 
    <li>Item 2</li> 
    <li>Item 3</li> 
  </div>
  <div class="three column">
    <li>Item 4</li> 
    <li>Item 5</li> 
    <li>Item 6</li> 
  </div>
  <div class="three column">
    <li>Item 7</li> 
    <li>Item 8</li> 
    <li>Item 9</li> 
  </div>
</ul>
```

I am inserting li's inside div which is within ul. What do you think? Is this stucture semantically valid and will that be recognized as a single list?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, `div` is not allowed as a direct child of `ul`. Whenever you're in doubt, [validate your page with W3C](http://validator.w3.org) or check [the corresponding article on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element):

> #### 4.5.6 The ul element
>
> **Categories**
> [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content).
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
> Where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content) is expected.
>
> **Content model:**
> Zero or more li elements.
>
> **Content attributes:**
> [Global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes)
>
> **DOM interface:**
> `interface HTMLUListElement : HTMLElement {};`

Instead you could use

```
<ul class="blog-category">
    <li class="three column">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="three column">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div>`'s aren't technically valid inside of `<ul>`'s. W3 validator returns this result:

> Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context

It would make more sense to group the code you have different, such as:

```
<div class="blog-category">
<ul class="three-column">
    <li>Item 1</li> 
    <li>Item 2</li> 
    <li>Item 3</li> 
    <li>Item 4</li> 
    <li>Item 5</li> 
    <li>Item 6</li> 
    <li>Item 7</li> 
    <li>Item 8</li> 
    <li>Item 9</li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not valid, neither in HTML4, nor in XHTML or in HTML5.

If you'll validate this against the [w3c markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) you'll probably get something like:

> Element div not allowed as child of element ul

More about lists can be found [here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is valid also do the following:

```
          <ul>
            <li>
                <div>Title</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>Title</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I've checked in http://validator.w3.org/check