# Split <ul> into two divs one for first-child and one for the rest

Tags: jquery, html

using jquery i would like to split ul li tags into two divs

Example

```
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
<li>4th</li>
<li>5th</li>
<li>6th</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
    </ul>
     </div>

<div class="left">
        <ul>
         <li>second</li>
         <li>third</li>
         <li>4th</li>
         <li>5th</li>
         <li>6th</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

this method i will use for scrolling the left section only with fixed right one

Comment: Div is not allowed as a direct child of ul. Please check this approach as a possible duplicated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557869/is-this-html-structure-valid-ul-div-li-li-div-li-li-div

Comment: your html is invalid..

Comment: now i changed the code to be valid thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your html is [**`invalid`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557869/is-this-html-structure-valid-ul-div-li-li-div-li-li-div?lq=1) (`li` should not be wrapped inside a `div`) you can try like,

```
var li = $('li');

li.filter(':first').wrap('<div class="right"></div>');
li.filter(':not(:first)').wrapAll('<div class="left"></div>');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dT4c4/)

The following can make your html valid,

```
var li = $('li');

li.filter(':first').wrap('<div class="first"></div>').parent().wrap('<li></li>');
li.filter(':not(:first)').wrapAll('<div class="second"></div>').parent().wrap('<li></li>');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dT4c4/1/)

As per your new requirement you can do like,

```
var li = $('li');
$('ul').remove();

var leftLi = li.filter(':first').detach();
var rightLi = li.filter(':not(:first)').detach();

leftLi.appendTo($('body')).wrap('<ul></ul>').wrap('<div></div>');
rightLi.appendTo($('body')).wrapAll('<ul></ul>').wrap('<div></div>');
```

**Note:** you should take care of the `ids` and `classes` of the `ul` elements, since I don't know the html structure. And have you noticed that `.appendTo('body')`, I just written that for a demonstration purpose, but you have to decide where the elements should be appended.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dT4c4/4/)

Comment: Good but this method wrap all divs in the page "not first" to class="second" how to separate them

Comment: @user2862890 are you having any specific id for that ul.?

Comment: yes `#main-wrapper ul.label_with_thumbs li` but the question changed now beacause it not allowed div inside ul tag

Comment: @user2862890 Check out the update, and don't forget to accept this as your answer if it satisfies your need. :)

Comment: the same problem the code wrap all tags have the name because its like aboxs into html page i append it for the box and determine li accurate

Comment: @user2862890 Don't use the selectors that I given, you should have some other ids and classes for that ul elements in your code, just use that. or just post your html structure

Comment: here http://th3giant-template.blogspot.com for this direction `#main-wrapper .HTML .widget-content ul.label_with_thumbs li`