# HTML items showing up out of order

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple site that has multiple html items (in this case `h1`, `ul`, `li`, `div class ="test"`).

For some reason, two items don't show up in the correct order. I have a `ul` that has multiple `li` entries. Under that (in my code at least) I have a `p`.
However, when I run the HTML file, the `ul` uses the `p` as a point of reference for positioning itself with `margin-top: 110px;`. It's really stumping me. If you would like to see my code and run it for yourself, here you go:

Here is a [Demo of the code:](https://jsfiddle.net/zdb7du9L/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
    body    {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/114178/flashcards/759682/jpg/cumulus.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    h1  {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #CE4F04;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    }

    ul  {
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    }

    li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
        }
    .navigation-bar-items {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: grey;
    }
    .container { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
   }
    .mainLogo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #CE4F04;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    }
    .main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    .test {
    margin-top: 200px; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">

            <h1>Welcome to my blog</h1>

    </div>

    <ul>
        <div class="navigation-bar-items">

                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About me</li>
                <li>Social</li>
                <li>Contact Me</li>
                <li></li>

        </div>
    </ul>
</header>
<div class="test">Hello</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This might be personal preference, but I would put your background-color on your div element (block-level) instead of your h1 (inline-level), that way you will have more control over where the background color shows.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Will do, thanks! Any idea why the ul is positioning itself in relation to the div class test?

Comment: Do you understand the consequence of using position: fixed? Therein lies your answer. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @swift-newbie In fact I think I might. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `div` with class `test` has a `margin:top` set. This is pushing down your `<body>` element, which pushes down your other fixed element as well.

To fix this, use `position: relative` and `top` instead of `margin: top` on your `div` with class `test`.

**Live Example:**

```css
body
{
 background-image: url(https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/114178/flashcards/759682/jpg/cumulus.jpg);
 background-size: 100%;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}
h1
{
 background-color: white;
 color: #CE4F04;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 margin-right: -10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
ul
{
 background-color: aliceblue;
 left: 10px;
 margin-top: 110px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
li
{
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.navigation-bar-items
{
 color: grey;
 font-size: 30px;
}
.container
{
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
}
.mainLogo
{
 background-color: white;
 color: #CE4F04;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 margin-right: -10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.main
{
 background-color: aquamarine;
 margin-top: 1000px;
 max-width: 1000px;
}
.test
{
 position: relative;
 top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="container">
      <h1>Welcome to my blog</h1>
   </div>
   <ul>
      <div class="navigation-bar-items">
         <li>Home</li>
         <li>About me</li>
         <li>Social</li>
         <li>Contact Me</li>
         <li></li>
      </div>
   </ul>
</header>
<div class="test">Hello</div>
```

JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/zdb7du9L/2/

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to fix it! Means a lot to me.

Answer (score 2):

`div.test`'s top margin collapses with `body`'s top margin >> `body`'s top content edge moves down >> `ul` moves down. If you inhibits margin collapsing between `body` and `div.test` (by applying `padding-top` to `body`, for exemple), `ul` will be positioned as expected.

```css
body    {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/114178/flashcards/759682/jpg/cumulus.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   padding-top: 1px
    }

    h1  {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #CE4F04;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    }

    ul  {
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    }

    li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
        }
    .navigation-bar-items {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: grey;
    }
    .container { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
   }
    .mainLogo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #CE4F04;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    }
    .main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    .test {
    margin-top: 200px; 
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">

            <h1>Welcome to my blog</h1>

    </div>

    <ul>
        <div class="navigation-bar-items">

                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About me</li>
                <li>Social</li>
                <li>Contact Me</li>
                <li></li>

        </div>
    </ul>
</header>
<div class="test">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping the newer community who aren't experienced. Very thoughtful of you.

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

First, you can't have a `div` inside a `ul`. That's [invalid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557869/is-this-html-structure-valid-ul-div-li-li-div-li-li-div).

So wrap the `ul` inside the `div` instead.

```
<div class="navigation-bar-items">
    <ul>
       <li>Home</li>
       <li>About me</li>
       <li>Social</li>
       <li>Contact Me</li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Second, although you mention it in your question, there's no `<p>` (paragraph tag) in your code.

Third, the `<header>` element is intended for introductory or navigational content only. You've got a `#container` in there, too. If this container is intended for your primary body content, you may want to [revise that structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header), as well.

Fourth, once you've got your HTML clean and semantically correct, run it through the [W3C Mark-Up Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/). It will show you errors and warnings.

I understand that you need assistance with the CSS, as well. That's covered in other answers here. But save yourself tons of maintenance and troubleshooting frustration down the line: Get the HTML in order first. Then focus on your CSS.

Good luck!