# Having Issue on Wrapping li list in a Div indepenedntly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap each `li` in a div `.new` which works fine when the `li` doesn't have any children `<ul><li></li></ul>`.

but when it is in following format

```
<li>XRP 1
    <ul>
        <li>Company Maintenance</li>
        <li>Employees
            <ul>
                <li>Reports
                    <ul>
                        <li>Report1</li>
                        <li>Report2</li>
                        <li>Report3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Employee Maint.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Human Resources</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>XRP 2</li>
<li>XRP 3</li>
```

It wraps `li`s in `new` in the hierarchy several times

```js
$( "li" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

```css
.new {
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
    margin:5px; 
}
```

is there any way that I can add open and closing tag before each item?

Comment: Do you want to wrap only the outer LI with the DIV? Or are you trying to wrap all the LIs?

Comment: No I would like to wrap all Li (outers and Iners)

Comment: Is there a reason `$('li').addClass('new')` will not work?

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you want to do (I'm not sure):

```
<ul>
    <div><li></li></div>
</ul>
```

This is not valid HTML.
Explanation here: [Is this HTML structure valid? UL > DIV > { LI, LI } , DIV > { LI, LI } , DIV > { LI, LI }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557869/is-this-html-structure-valid-ul-div-li-li-div-li-li-div)

Comment: Thanks Louys, you are right. so what is the solution then?

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do... But if it is only to add the class .new, You shoul use addClass on li instead of wrapping with a div.